# How to retrieve the list of repositories in a specified github account using Jgit API?

Tags: java, eclipse, jgit

As I requested to validate the user has the repository which he provided. So I need to list out the repositories belongs to the particular User by using their credentials . I'm using Eclipse's Jgit to handle git-hub from Java code. Whether this API provides any pre-built method for this?? Please Guide me through this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In order to list the repositories that belong to a GitHub user account, you'll want to use the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/). The API is language-independent, all data is sent and received as JSON over HTTP. Java wrapper libraries are listed on the [GitHub libraries page](https://developer.github.com/libraries/)

Once you figured the repository that is to be accessed, you can use JGit to clone it.

Comment: Will it gives me the repositories also which the user doesn't create but having permission for commit and push Operations?? I need that repositories too?? Can I able to achieve this??

Comment: Did you read the [GitHub API documentation for repositories](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/)? It's all there.

Comment: Yeah.. I read it. But bit confused about how to do this from Java code.